# How to solve system equations with sum and vectors

Tags: equation-solving

I`m trying to solve this system of equations relatively $\beta$:
$\sum_{i=1}^{3}w_i(r_i-x_i*\beta)x_i^T=\vec0$

where is $\beta$ - column vector, $x_i$-row vector.

I use this sample code:

```
w = {4, 3, 5};
r = {1, 2, 3};
x = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
vec = {{0}, {0}};
Solve[Sum[ 
w[[i]]*(r[[i]] - x[[i]].beta)[[1]]*Transpose[{x[[i]]}], {i, 1, 
 3}] == vec, beta];
```

Output: Solve::ivar: {1} is not a valid variable. There is a problem?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Now my output is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
w = {4, 3, 5};
r = {1, 2, 3};
x = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
beta = {\[Beta][1], \[Beta][2]};
Solve[(w (r - x.beta)).x == {0, 0}, beta]
```

> {{[Beta][1] -> -1, [Beta][2] -> 1}}

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: You're welcome! =D